# Text overlapping icon in combobox

Tags: python, css, qt, combobox, pyside

I have a qss file that contains all the styling for a project. In this file I define that I don't want to see any indicator in the comboboxes:

```
QComboBox::indicator{
    background-color: transparent;
    color: transparent;
    selection-background-color: transparent;
    selection-color: transparent;
}
```

This makes the indicator transparent, but there is still some weird indicator artefact on the left of the text. But adding this makes it disappear:

```
QComboBox::item:selected
{
    /* If we don't specify a border we get an indicator reserved space to the left. (??) */
    border: none;
    background-color: @BG_SELECTED;
    color: @FG_SELECTED;
}
```

Now it's perfect on a combobox where there is no icon, the text is pushed to the far left and it looks neat. The problem now, is that the text is also pushed to the left when there is an icon. Which means that the text is overlapping the icon.
I fixed it by doing:

```
QComboBox::item
{
    height: 10px;
    margin: 5px 0 0 5px;
    padding: 6px 0 5px 20px;
}
```

But the problem is that it also affects the one without an icon, making a white empty space on the left of my combobox drop-down.

Does anyone know how to either make it move to the left if there is an icon or maybe access the icon and make it take some space???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out a way to solve this issue with a workaround as it does not seem like it's possible with PySide using only qss.

What I did is suppress this from my qss file:

```
QComboBox::item
{
    height: 10px;
    margin: 5px 0 0 5px;
    padding: 6px 0 5px 20px;
}
```

And modified my ui file by adding the above piece of styling to every combobox that needed it.